# Fourier transform of $e^{-i\pi x^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, fourier-transform

I am looking for the Fourier transform of the function 
$$
f(x):=e^{-i\pi x^2},
$$
where we define 
$$
\hat f(\xi):=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)e^{-2\pi i x\xi}dx.
$$
First of all, the function $f$ is not integrable, but it is bounded and hence it can be regarded as a tempered distribution on $\mathcal S$, the Schwartz function space.

Completing squares as usual, it strongly suggests that its Fourier transform, in the sense of tempered distributions, is given by
$$
\frac 1 {\sqrt i} e^{ i\pi \xi^2}.
$$
The only problem is that I dont know how to determine the branch of $\sqrt i$. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\pi x^2} e^{-2\pi i x \xi} dx 
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\pi [(x+\xi)^2-\xi^2]} dx \\
&= e^{i\pi \xi^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\pi x^2} dx \\
&= \frac{e^{i\pi \xi^2}}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{aligned}$$

The last integral (Fresnel function) is easily evaluated using a circular arc contour subtending an angle of $\pi/4$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Then it seems that my guess for the answer was wrong, and we cannot treat $i$ as if it were real, right?

Comment: @ThomasYang  The formula $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a\pi x^2}e^{-2\pi i x \xi} dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} e^{-\pi \xi^2/a}$$ only holds when $a>0$. If you treat $a$ as a complex number, the path of integration will no longer be the real line, this causes problems.